# how to connect remote oracle database using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, oracle

I am trying to write code to connect remote oracle database using Ruby? Can any one help me in this?

Comment: What have your tried/researched so far?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do so, however it's off-topic on Stack Overflow to request recommendations for off-site resources. Instead, you need to do the research, then try some things, and when you've run into a problem ask a question about that specific thing. I'd suggest you start your search by [checking Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+orm) and the search engines looking for "Ruby + ORM + Oracle". All the Ruby ORMs can talk to Oracle nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The OCI8 gem is what you want:

https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8

You will obviously also need an Oracle client installed.  If you don't already have one, the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) would be recommended.

Comment: It does work. Not sure why the original poster has not accepted it yet.